# How to Fix/Clean Lambda warnings/errors from Views PHP

Tags: 7, views

I used views php to get the values from the field collection of the saved node in order to create a front end select list on views.

[image]

It does what I wanted it to do but there are a bunch of warnings and notice and I would like to clean it.

This is just a part of the warning and notice that appeared.

[image]

And this:
[image]

It's a repetition of errors for my different variables.

This is an example of my code:

```
<select class="number_of_person">

    <?php
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $row->nid);
    if (isset($wrapper->field_criteria)) { 
    $prices_number_of_person= array();
    $min_and_max_number_of_person = array();
        foreach ($wrapper->field_criteria as $i){
              $price_loop1[] = $i->field_price->value();
              $min_and_max_loop1[] = $i->field_criteria_name->value();

        }
         $prices_number_of_person= implode(",", $price_loop1);
         $min_and_max_number_of_person = implode(",", $min_and_max_loop1 );


         $split_min_and_max_number_of_person = explode(",", $min_and_max_number_of_person );
         $split_prices_number_of_person = explode(",", $prices_number_of_person);

         $length_number_of_person = count($split_min_and_max_number_of_person);


        for ($number_of_person=0; $number_of_person < $length_number_of_person; $number_of_person++) {

        if($split_prices_number_of_person[$number_of_person] !="" ){
         echo '<option value="'.$split_prices_number_of_person[$number_of_person].'" class="options">'.$split_min_and_max_number_of_person[$number_of_person].'... + ₱ '.$split_prices_number_of_person[$number_of_person].'</option>';
        }

         else{
          echo '<option value="'.$split_prices_number_of_person[$number_of_person].'" class="options">'.$split_min_and_max_number_of_person[$number_of_person].'</option>';

              }
         }

     }
    ?>

    </select>
```

I was wondering if there is something that I need to add to my code to get rid of the warning and notice?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This question is not much about Drupal, since the code to avoid warnings and notices is not different from the code you would use when programming in plain PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before try to explode/implode  check that data exist in them 
as example

```
"$price_loop1"   
 if($price_loop1) 
     $prices_number_of_person= implode(",", $price_loop1);
```

and for explode

```
  if($prices_number_of_person)
      $split_prices_number_of_person = explode(",", $prices_number_of_person);
```